# Proteger input de ataque scripting

Tags: php, javascript

Queria saber como proteger o input de ataques com códigos script nas caixas de input, se alguém souber como fazer ajudava muito

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php?page=dados_encomenda">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name= "nome" id="nome" placeholder="Introduza o seu nome" required>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon">
   </span>Encomendar</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que deve fazer é utilizar o `htmlentities()` na hora de **exibir** o resultado.

Isto é vulnerável:

```
// Input:
$Nome = $_POST['nome'];

// Output:
echo $Nome;
```

Isto é relativamente seguro contra XSS:

```
// Input:
$Nome = $_POST['nome'];

// Output:  
echo htmlentities($Nome, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, 'UTF-8');
```

---

O `ENT_QUOTES` é utilizado para que o PHP escape o `'` e também o `"`. Já o `ENT_HTML5` e o `UTF-8` é utilizado para que definimos a "linguagem" que estamos "se comunicando", basicamente o mesmo principio que temos que fazer quando utilizamos o [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string/12118602#12118602). Para ter certeza de temos o controle sobre a codificação do caractere e que ele seja o mesmo especificado pelo o `htmlentities` defina o mesmo no `<meta>` e também no *header* de `Content-Type`.

Nunca salve o resultado do `htmlentities`, o [Wordpress](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress), *que publicamente diz que segurança não é prioridade*, já fez isso no passado. O Wordpress [falhou uma vez](https://cedricvb.be/post/wordpress-stored-xss-vulnerability-4-1-2/) e [depois novamente fracassou](https://klikki.fi/adv/wordpress2.html).

---

**Como tudo pode dar errado...**

Ainda temos alguns recursos para prevenir que os danos de um XSS sejam maiores, defina um *cookie* para "httpOnly" e "Secure", *requer HTTPS*, utilizando:

```
session.cookie_httponly = On
session.cookie_secure = On
```

Utilize o cabeçalho de `Content-Security-Policy` para prevenir carregar conteúdo externo ao site e definir quais sites são confiáveis, por exemplo:

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'self' https://cdn.example.net https://ajax.googleapis.com https://www.google-analytics.com; child-src 'none'; object-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests
```

Isto irá impedir que alguém carregue um `script` de *inseguro.com*.

---

**Links recomendados:**

- [XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet)
- [PHP Security Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Security_Cheat_Sheet)
- [WordPress < 4.1.2 Stored XSS vulnerability](https://cedricvb.be/post/wordpress-stored-xss-vulnerability-4-1-2/)
- [WordPress 4.2 Stored XSS](https://klikki.fi/adv/wordpress2.html)
- [Build your Content-Security-Policy](https://report-uri.io/home/generate)